# Check null parameter in NamedQuery

Tags: hibernate, hql, named-query

When a column is numeric type I usually use this parameter verification in my named queries:

```
(-1 = ?1 OR column = ?1)
```

But with a date filter using between i can't do the same type of verification:

```
(p.date between ?1 and ?2)
```

The solution I found was to add a new parameter checking whether the date is null:

```
(dateInitial == null || dateFinal == null)
```

In named query:

```
(?3 = true OR p.date between ?1 and ?2)
```

- Is there a solution that i don't need to add another parameter? Using the existing parameters.

Comment: Could you check the dates before invoking the named query?

Comment: Yes, and i did it: `(dateInitial == null || dateFinal == null)`. You talking about send another value in case of null?

Comment: Not an answer to your question really, I'm just saying check the dates in the code and if null don't invoke the named query. Do you have null dates in the database?

Comment: I understand, but in my case i have others parameters to check too, no i don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
(p.date between ?1 and ?2)
```

You can try

```
(p.date < ?1 or ?1 is null) and (p.date > ?2 or ?2 is null)
```

Comment: Thanks,  i have tried ?1 is null too but jdbc driver give me an exception ORA-00932 (inconsistent datatypes). The order of operators is `> ?1` and `< ?2`, right?

Comment: you can try ?1 ?2 ?3 ?4 passing for ?1 and ?2 the same value